# Getting events of a JS object using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Hi I am using the following code to

```
var view = new storeLocator.View(); //it has an event called load

$(view).on("load",function(){
  alert("Gochcha!!");
return true;
})
```

But I don know why I never get the alert to fired ? Can anybody please tell me what am I missing ?

I think the code snippet din make things clear. Lemme share the entire code I am trying:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-28, 135),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var panelDiv = $('#panel');
  var data = new MyDataSource;
  var view = new storeLocator.View(map, data, {
    geolocation: true,
    features: data.getFeatures()
  });

$(view).on("load",function(){
  alert("Gochcha!!");
return true;
 })

});//End of map load
```

What I am trying is not Triggering the event, but binding my function to an event of a javascript object, so that whenever the event fires I get my function called first and then continue what it was suppose to do. The even does fire as I see the map and the data get loaded but I am not getting my function to get working.

Comment: what is the Jquery version ? because `.on` function does not support in 1.6 and earlier

Comment: jQuery's `on()` used that way is a wrapper of sorts for the native `onload` function, and binding with `on()` would bind to the `onload` function and fire when something, well, loads. It does'nt neccessarely mean it will bind to some custom load function defined in an object, but that would depend on how that load function is defined etc.

Comment: Have you tried binding it via - `view.load(function(){ \\code here })`?

Comment: I am using 1.8.2. @adeneo0.: so what are you suggesting ? kayen: tried that- no luck.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the context in which you are raising the event is the `view` otherwise this wont get caught

Comment: Hi Sharma: Just updated the code. Could you please suggest if I am on the right context or not ?!

Comment: you should also include storeLocator code here OR if this part of code written by you please give a link of where it is present

Comment: Here you go:http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/index.html?utm_campaign=sl&utm_source=youtube